# Grails: How can I search through children in a hasMany relationship?

Tags: grails

If I have a Client domain class, and that Client hasMany Courses.  How do I find the course I'm looking for?  For instance:

```
class Client {
    String name
    static hasMany = [courses:Course]
}

class Course {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [client:Client]
}

def client = Client.get(1)
```

I want to "find" or "search" within that courses relationship. Maybe something like:

```
client.courses.find(name:'Whatever')
```

Is there any way to do this with Grails?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're using a second level cache and have configured it for this association, you might want to iterate over the collection (this will save you a database query if the association is in cache).

Here is an example using the clever [Groovy Collection API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html):

```
def course = client.courses.find { it.name == "whatever" }
```

Important: If you decide to take this approach make sure to [configure eager / batch fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654704/grails-gorm-default-fetch-strategy-when-to-set-fetchmode-to-eager-eager-vs) of `courses` so you don't run into [the n+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem).

Comment: is this approach better than the next one?

Comment: It depends on your use case. You should really avoid using associations if it can grow without bounds, but for associations limited to a few entities ( < 10?) this will probably do just fine for a lot of use cases.

Comment: I would recommend encapsulating the search code in a service method or in the domain class itself (as a getter method) so that you can easily try out different implementations in a benchmark with real-world data.

Answer (score 12):

One way is with dynamic finder methods:

```
Courses.findAllByClientAndName(client, 'whatever')
```

This would get all a client's courses named 'whatever'.

Grails also has [few other ways](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying) to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you do if you don't have the belongsTo setup?

Comment: You can query on the joining column instead.  For example `findAllByClientIdAndName` if the `Course` object has a `clientId` property.  It depends on how your domain expresses the relationship between the two objects.