# Find all objects with value in list

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm introducing myself to the Grails environment (It's *awesome*). I've been reaping the benefits of dynamically generated methods like the `findAllBy*` range. However, I've come to a problem and I'm unsure about how to proceed. An hour spent on Google didn't yield all that much for me either.

**Problem**

I have a class like the following:

```
class Runner {

    static hasMany = [owners: Owner]
}
```

And in my Owner controller, I wish to find all `Runner` objects, that contain a given `Owner`. Effectively, I'm trying to go from the `many` to the `one`.

**Example**

If I have an `Owner` object, that looks something like

```
Owner[name="Dave"]
```

And I have a `Runner` with something like:

```
Runner[owners[Owner[name="Dave"], Owner[name="James"]]]
```

My query should return this `Runner` object, but it should not return

```
Runner[owners[Owner[name="Bill"], Owner[name="James"]]]
```

**My attempts**

I've attempted to use the `inList` extension, but after some further research I realised that was designed for the other way around. My code at the moment is as follows:

```
def runners() {
    log.info("Runners")
    List<Runner> runners;
    Owner owner;

    if (params.id) {
        log.info("Id = " + params.id);
        owner = Owner.get(params.id);
        log.info("owner = " + owner.name);
        // Grab runners in list thing.
        log.info("Number of results = " + runners.size());
    }


    [results: results, jockeyInstance: jockey]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails: How can I search through children in a hasMany relationship?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437446/grails-how-can-i-search-through-children-in-a-hasmany-relationship)

Comment: what problem do you have with `inList`? should work for this case

Comment: `inList`, according to the documentation was for the other way around. For when I'm passing a `List` in, and if the element in the class is inside that `List`, then return it.

Comment: @christopher Oh, I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research into `HQL`, I found a more elegant solution that didn't require me to change the `Domain` classes at all. The query I used was as follows:

```
runners = Runner.executeQuery("FROM Runner as r WHERE :owner in elements(r.owners)", [owner : ownerInstance]);
```

Where `ownerInstance` is the `Owner` object being used to map to the `Runner`.

Comment: i tried it with the code from my answer and it works like advertised. this should be considered the answer.

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the answer for the question at hand, but you could also make the runners known to the owners like this

```
    class Runner {
            String name
            static hasMany = [ owners: Owner ]
            static belongsTo = Owner
    }


    class Owner {
            String name
            static hasMany = [ runners: Runner ]
    }

    Owner o1 = new Owner(name: "O1").save()
    Owner o2 = new Owner(name: "O2").save()
    Owner o3 = new Owner(name: "O3").save()
    new Runner(name: "R1").with{
            addToOwners(o1)
            addToOwners(o2)
            save()
    }
    new Runner(name: "R2").with{
            addToOwners(o1)
            addToOwners(o3)
            save()
    }
    print o3.runners
```

results in `[runnerowner.Runner : 2]`

Comment: This is definitely *one* option, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are expecting?

```
def results = Runner.withCriteria {
    owners {
        eq 'name', 'Dave'
        //idEq params.id //If id of owner is provided
    }
}
```

assuming you have

```
class Runner {
    static hasMany = [owners: Owner]
}

class Owner {
    String name
}
```

Here is a [sample](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6994906/) you can try.