# Grails GORM domain class with hasMany of same type and duplicate entries

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

In simple terms it's an inventory system, that is tied to SKU's. The SKU is a composite of items, sometimes multiples of the exact same item.

E.G

SKU for a dining room set would be, 4(Item)"chair" and 1(Item)"table". If I could get GORN to recognize it's tied to multiple instances of "chair", so I can keep count.

Here's the basic code as I've tried

```
class Item implements Serializable{
    String name;
    String description;

}

class Sku {
    String description;
    String skuCode;
    Collection items;
    static hasMany = [items:Item];
}
//… GENERATE TEST DATA
    item = new Item(name:"Table", description:"Oak table");
    item.save();

    item = new Item(name:"Chair", description:"Oak chair");
    item.save();

    sku= new Sku(description:"A complete dining room set for 4");
    sku.items = [Item.findByName("Table"),Item.findByName("Chair"),
                     Item.findByName("Chair"),Item.findByName("Chair"),
                     Item.findByName("Chair")];
    sku.save();
```

This will only show the SKU as being of "Table" and "Chair".

I'm not even sure how to do this in SQL. But I would like to know if there's a construct that can accomplish what I want. This seems like it would be a clean way to code it.

The end goal is a system that SKU will contain many different item combos, and I'll want to be able to narrow down possible SKU's by entering item combo's.

E.G If I search for Table + 1 chair, I would see Table & 4Chairs and table + 2 chairs (after it's inserted) etc. Or Table+Chair(s)+Island+Stools(s)+Fridge

Thanks

Comment: I think you are in the good track. Even when i do not like your schema very much i think it should be possible to acomplish the queries you need with it in it's actual state. Can you describe your problem in more detail? ... what do you mean by "This will only show the SKU as being of "Table" and "Chair". "

Comment: What's wrong with the schema? Keep in mind it's not what I'm really building, it's the simplest way I could explain my plan. But I'm new to GORM so I could be missing something really obvious.

Comment: If I were to do this in a more strictly Java entityish way, I could use a map of Map<Item,Integer> so it would be <"Chair",4>. But that locks me in to tracking count for every single item (maybe not a bad thing?)

Comment: Nothing serious ... lets focus on the problems you actually have ... can you describe it in more detail? ... i do not understand what is the question here.

Comment: I was saying that instead of counting objects based on association, I would instead explicitly count them them ahead of time. I don't like that since it means having to always check the count after adding/removing. It's me bouncing around ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a little digging into documentation to figure it out.

Zoidberg is right that GORM defaults to a set. I had used Collection as my understanding was, that was an unordered list that could contain duplicates. [The documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps) lead me to try a List. List allows duplicates. It does make a mention of performance about using lists, so read that part too. That was my reasoning for using Collection at first, but that does not seem to work as I need it.

The other issue is how to query based on a partial list. E.G Return all SKU's that have the item "Chair" present somewhere.

[This SO answer ended up being my solution to that piece.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22012781/288915)

So here is my example code as it stands.

```
class Item implements Serializable{
    String name;
    String description;

}

class Sku {
    String description;
    String skuCode;
    List items;
    static hasMany = [items:Item];
    }

//… GENERATE TEST DATA
item = new Item(name:"Table", description:"Oak table");
item.save();

item = new Item(name:"Chair", description:"Oak chair");
item.save();

sku= new Sku(description:"A complete dining room set for 4");
sku.items = [Item.findByName("Table"),Item.findByName("Chair"),
                 Item.findByName("Chair"),Item.findByName("Chair"),
                 Item.findByName("Chair")];
sku.save();

//Query test data
Sku.executeQuery("FROM Sku as s WHERE :item in elements(s.items)",
    [item: Item.findByName("Chair")]) 
//returns List<Sku> of any Sku's that contain the item "chair". 
//I need to create a version that takes a list, so I can narrow the search.
```

[This issue in Jira](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11872) with GORM is very similar to the one I get if I attempt to use findByItemsInList, or any other findBy*.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same Item 4 Times (the chair).

```
sku.items = [Item.findByName("Table"),Item.findByName("Chair"),
                     Item.findByName("Chair"),Item.findByName("Chair"),
                     Item.findByName("Chair")];
```

But by default GORM will create a Set. See:
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html

And sets can't contain duplicates. If you want to keep count you could add an Integer to count your Item and increment/ decrement it if you use it.

Or create as many Items with the name 'chair' as you need.

Comment: I'm figuring out that using List might be my solution. I need to work it out a little more to be sure. List will allow duplicates, and store them in order of being added. Using scaffolding, I can look at the items quickly and it's storing properly. 

Querying will be trickier, but I think I have that solved too:
`Sku.executeQuery("FROM Sku as s WHERE :item in elements(s.items)",[item: Item.findByName("Chair")])` will return any SKU that contains 1 or more chair.

Comment: I used Collection originally to solve my Set problem, but newer documentation has shown me that's not the right way