# How do you turn off hibernate lazy loading for all domain classes in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, jaxb

The question states what I want to do. I have a bunch of classes with attributes annotated with JAXB annotations, and the results are coming back blank because of lazy loading I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are [gorm.default.mappings](http://www.grails.org/1.2+Release+Notes) but I see nothing documented for setting the property you want

I know you can brute force it this way

```
// DataSource.groovy
hibernate {
    max_fetch_depth=0
}
```

But I believe overall it is better to leave the configuration the way it is. I can explain it but this [question/response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654704/grails-gorm-default-fetch-strategy-when-to-set-fetchmode-to-eager-eager-vs) covers it and it already typed up

Comment: I realize the performance implications - but if I can't reliably get data marshalled to XML my application is basically useless...I tried to set lazy:false for particular properties in the mapping of the domain and I still didnt get the right thing back

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply use `fetchType=EAGER`