# Grails / GORM: difference between lazy: false & fetchMode eager

Tags: grails, grails-orm, lazy-loading, fetch, eager-loading

In Grails / GORM, what is the difference between `static mapping = {xyz lazy: false}` & `static fetchMode = [xyz: 'eager']`?

Example:

```
class Book {
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
    static mapping   = {author  lazy: false}
    static fetchMode = [author: 'eager']
}
```

Comment: I think this might answer your question: 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654704/grails-gorm-default-fetch-strategy-when-to-set-fetchmode-to-eager-eager-vs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654704/grails-gorm-default-fetch-strategy-when-to-set-fetchmode-to-eager-eager-vs

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the answer seems to describe the difference between `lazy: true` & `lazy: false`.  The answer doesn't mention `fetchMode = [...]`

Comment: It would be nice it someone could answer this question as I didn't find any explanation on the grails documentation neither on the internet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between **lazy:false** and **fetchMode 'eager'** are

1. lazy:false will get the associated domain object by querying again to database using Select Query, but fetchMode 'eager' which is deprecated now(use fetch:'join') will try to join the associated tables(using outer join) and fetch the associated objects in single query.
2. lazy:false will have one more query to the database to fetch the associated domain object and hence would be having more interactions with the database whereas fetch:'join' will have less interaction to fetch the same data.
3. FetchMode Join overrides the lazy property. It will simple ignore the lazy:false.

Should you be interested in a detailed explanation about Fetchmodes, take a look http://www.solidsyntax.be/2013/10/17/fetching-collections-hibernate/. The article describes the Hibernate fetchmodes and the output which they produce.

Hope this helps.